# How do you add an EC2 instance created with ec2 module to ~/.ssh/known_hosts?

Tags: ssh, ansible

Let's say I have this ec2 task (taken from the [documentation](http://ansible-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ec2_module.html)) in a file named site.yml:

```
# Basic provisioning example
- ec2:
  key_name: mykey
  instance_type: t2.micro
  image: ami-123456
  wait: yes
  group: webserver
  count: 3
  vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
  assign_public_ip: yes
```

Assuming I register the ec2 module result into a variable named ec2_instances, what would I do to add that single ec2 instance to my ~/.ssh/known_hosts file so that I can easily ssh into the new instance?

I've looked at the [known_hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/known_hosts_module.html) module and its example is:

```
- name: tell the host about our servers it might want to ssh to
  known_hosts:
  path: /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  name: foo.com.invalid
  key: "{{ lookup('file', 'pubkeys/foo.com.invalid') }}"
```

Every property makes sense to me except for the key property.  Regarding the lookup plugin, I don't have any file containing public keys for my new instance (that I know of).  What should I provide for the key property?

The documentation for the key property is:

> The SSH public host key, as a string (required if state=present,
>   optional when state=absent, in which case all keys for the host are
>   removed). The key must be in the right format for ssh (see sshd(8),
>   section "SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS FILE FORMAT")

I have looked into the sshd(8) [manual entry](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sshd.8.html) and here are the relevant paragraphs (emphasis mine):

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers
>   (optional), hostnames, keytype, base64-encoded **key**, comment. The
>   fields are separated by spaces.
>
> The keytype and base64-encoded **key** are taken directly from the **host**
>   **key**; they can be obtained, for example, from
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub. The optional comment field continues to
>   the end of the line, and is not used.

How do I get the key I need to add to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file?  This sounds like a common task so before I put forth potentially unnecessary effort to build my own solution, I thought I'd check to see if I was just missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to avoid the prompt asking if you want to connect to X server?

Comment: I want to ensure that I'm connecting to the server I think I'm connecting to via the ssh command.  I won't be using X server, just a terminal connection.  Thanks @nbari!

Comment: What about `StrictHostKeyChecking ask` in your ssh config? or probably `ssh-keyscan -H <the IP of your instances>  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @nbari the ssh-keyscan option sounds like the best fit for me (I don't want everyone on my team to have to modify their ssh config).  I'll try this approach out and get back to you.  Thanks!